# How to extract dates from string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract dates from string by excel formula only. Below is my data sample

```
Only contains one date 01/05/2021 to this example
Project start date is 01/01/2021 and end date is 31/01/2021
There may multiple date like 1st 01/01/2021 2nd 01/06/2021 and 3rd 31/12/2021
```

[image]

My computer local date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`. I was trying to accomplish it by `FILTERXML()` formula. I have tried below formula, also tried few other methods but fails.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,'dd/mm/yyyy','')!=.]"))
```

My expected output looks like-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go purely xpath then you could try to fully validate your pattern `dd/mm/yyyy` in a few steps:<sub>1</sub>

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., 3, 1)= '/'][substring(., 6, 1)= '/'][string-length(translate(., '/' , '')) = 8][translate(., '/' , '')*0=0]"),"dd/mm/e"))
```

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` - Create a valid XML-construct.
- `//s` - Select s-nodes where:

  - `[substring(., 3, 1)= '/']` - There is a forward slash at the 3rd index;
  - `[substring(., 6, 1)= '/']` - There is a forward slash at the 6th index;
  - `[string-length(translate(., '/' , '')) = 8]` - The remainder of the node when we replace the forward slashes is of length eight.
  - `[translate(., '/' , '')*0=0]` - The remainder of the node when we replace the forward slashes is numeric.

Needless to say that if your string does not hold any other forward slashes but those in the dates you can simplify the above significantly<sub>1</sub>:

```
=TRANSPOSE(TEXT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., '/')]"),"dd/mm/e"))
```

[image]

Notice that if "dd/mm/yyyy" is recognized by Excel as dates, the returned array of simply using `//s` would return the numeric equivalent of these dates. If no other numeric values exist in your string you could benefit from that using Microsoft365 functionality<sub>1</sub>:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TRANSPOSE(TEXT(FILTER(X,ISNUMBER(X)),"dd/mm/e")))
```

<sub>1: **Note** that you can remove the nested `TEXT()` function and numberformat your cells to `dd/mm/e` too.</sub>

Comment: Understood! Removing `TEXT()` will make the formula clean and shorter. Just I need to format my excel cells to proper date format. Thanks for you nice explanation.