# excel subtraction with two or more dates

Tags: excel

any excel formula to subtract cells separated by comma (textjoin etc etc)
example:

```
A1 has this data (10/01/2021,20/03/2021)
A2 has this data (15/01/2021,26/03/2021)
```

I want to subtract `A2-A1` which is `(15/01/2021-10/01/2021,26/03/2021-20/03/2021)`

output would be `(5,6)`

Note A1 and A2 might not have equal set of dates. A1 might have only two dates, A2 might have only two or four etc etc and vice-versa. Ideally first date of A2 should should be subtracted from first date of A1 and so on)

Comment: There's no way to do that with a formula.  There are too many variables.   You'll have to write a VBA function to decode the strings and do your business logic

Comment: Does this answer your question. [Extract dates from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65952087/5514747)

Answer (score 0):

If your dates are always entered with this format, you can do it with this silly thing;
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(RIGHT($A$2,LEN($A$2)-1),10)-LEFT(RIGHT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-1),10),",",(RIGHT(LEFT($A$2,LEN($A$2)-1),10)-RIGHT(LEFT($A$1,LEN($A$1)-1),10)))

I had to change the date formatting to MM/DD/YYYY because my system is set to United States and it wasn't working the with DD/MM/YYYY.

But, VBA would probably be more reliable.

EDIT: Sorry missed the part where you said dates may not always have only two dates. You could do it but its just a long sting of garbage that it would just be better to work in VBA.

[image: ScreenShotOfFormula]

Comment: eems it is working, thankyou for that long formula. However even if format changes example (DD/MM/YYY OR MM/DD/YYYY which is 10 characters or DD-MMM-YYYY or MMM-DD-YYYY which are 11 characters; formula is taking a toll. can you suggest me VBA for this. and sorry that my data is not at A1,A2 (It is at A1,B1 and a series all down)

Comment: any vbascrip please